# How to get only headers with HTTP GET request without fetching the body

Tags: c#, http

Is there an opportunity to make http get request, read headers and not fetching body in order to reduce traffic and increase speed?
I use this code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(u1);
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        request.Timeout = 30000;
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36";
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        HttpWebResponse response;

        using (response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            var res = response.ResponseUri.ToString();
        }
```

So I need only the result url. If there is a redirection (Location header) - I will get the result url. But I don't need the body. Is it real to get response with GET method (not HEAD method) to get the result without the response body?

Comment: You should learn about `HEAD` requests. The response body is (at least partially) already on its way with a `GET`. You can ignore it, but it still comes and costs unnecessary bandwidth.

Comment: @spender also a good point, though reading headers and then dropping the connection would likely avoid most body (if body is large enough) to actually be transferred on the wire. That certainly would be a bad practice and hacky.

Comment: @LB2 : Dropping the connection has hidden costs too. It breaks HTTP 1.1 pipelining and, when you're really thrashing things, the port can't be reused during the TIME_WAIT period which can lead to port exhaustion.

Comment: @spender - Agreed.  That's exactly what I meant by _bad practice_.  It's a bad idea to drop connections to avoid traffic.  That's why made the comment to help prevent others from coming up with that idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `GET` on a resource that returns a body implies that you want to get the body.  `HEAD` is designed exactly for what you're seeking, assuming the server resource supports it.

If server doesn't support `HEAD`, you could potentially play with [`Range` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range) to just request a few bytes, but that also depends on resource supporting it, and is kind of a hack.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Headers property of HttpRequest

```
response.Headers
```

to get the headers for the response.

Comment: This let's you read the headers that OP is already doing.  That doesn't stop body from being transferred to reduce traffic.